# How to write mongodb search in golang using mgo

Tags: go, mgo

Here is my JSON file:

```
[{
    "name": "chetan",
    "age": 23,
    "hobby": ["cricket", "football"]
}, {
    "name": "raj",
    "age": 24,
    "hobby": ["cricket", "golf"]
}]
```

Here is the golang code I tried but didn't work as expected.

```
id:= "ket"
c.EnsureIndexKey("hobby")
err = c.Find(bson.M{"$hobby": bson.M{"$search": id,},}).All(&result)
```

It gives error:

> $hobby exit status 1

Comment: Are you trying to find documents with hobbies that contain the text `ket`?

Comment: yes i want to find the whose hobby contain ket like cricket in ket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `$search` I'm assuming you're trying to use a text index/search, but in your case that wouldn't work. Text index doesn't support partials. You can still use regex to find those documents, but performance wise it wouldn't be a wise choice probably, unless you can utilize the index - which in your case wouldn't happen.

Still, you could achieve what you want with:

```
id := "ket"
regex := bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{Pattern: id}}
err = c.Find(bson.M{"hobby": regex}).All(&result)
```